# Properties not mapping as part of a join?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, left-join, linq-to-entities

In a project I'm working on there seems to a mapping going on between the database table and the EF entity, done through configuration. Example:

```
builder.OwnsOne(
            o => o.ComplexProperty,
            sa =>
            {
                sa.Property(p => p.Property1).HasColumnName("Column1");
                sa.Property(p => p.Property2).HasColumnName("Column2");
            });
```

This property lives in an entity called `TestEntity`. This all works fine when making the following request:

```
 this.apiDbContext.TestEntity.ToList();
```

The `ComplexProperty`  has `Property1` and `Property2` filled correctly.

My issue is that I am doing some joining with this using LINQ:

```
from x in dataToJoinWith
join testEntity in dbContext.TestEntity on x.Id equals testEntity.XId into mJoin
from testEntity in mJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { TestEntity = testEntity };
```

At this point the `ComplexProperty` property of `TestEntity` is now null.

My questions is: how can I make this mapping from the configuration work when retrieving the data in a join?

I am using EF Core 6.
I have searched to the best of my ability. I am not very experienced with EF so I may not know the correct terms to search for.